# Icons do not appear on the ActionBar in the Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

hi there I try Make Material Design App Bar/ActionBar and Style It.

I am noob .. I try do it with [this tutorial](http://www.android4devs.com/2014/12/how-to-make-material-design-app.html)

I do all steps...But for last step, I can not add icon to action bar.

I use android studio last version and test SDK is 17

```
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_textsms"
        android:orderInCategory="200"
        android:title="textSMS"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_textsms"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        ></item>
</menu>
```

But the icon do not appear in android studio on emaulator (android4.2.2)

dose I define action_textsms correct? what is my wrong?

Comment: Try chaning ifRoom to always `app:showAsAction="always"`

Answer (score 0):

Check it out if in the styles.xml:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

</resources>
```

and in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
    ...
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `app:showAsAction="ifRoom"` to `app:showAsAction="always"`